# How to make string to object or array format

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have to create a string in format like below

```
  "currentState[0]['children'][1]"
```

But I need to execute it later just like below

```
  currentState[0]['children'][1]
```

I have elements and childrens on currentState. But while looping I have to create a string. But later I need to execute as array.

I have tried almost all array methods. Array.call, bind etc. And string methods as well. Could not get the output

How can I make it

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Use eval: `$str = "currentState[0]['children'][1]"`. Then: $test = eval($str);

Comment: You can use eval function. Eval will evaluate complete string

Comment: Yes `eval` will get the job done, **but**; `eval` is frowned upon because it can be used for a wide variaty of attacks on your code, your application, your user, ...

Answer (score 0):

Please be more specific with your question but from my understanding, you can use javascript's eval() function to execute a string as javascript, so when you need to execute it, just run `eval("currentState[0]['children'][1]")`.

The alternative to the eval() would be

`function evalFn(obj) {
  return Function('"use strict";return (' + obj + ')')();
}`

`evalFn("currentState[0]['children'][1]")`

refer to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval for a more in-depth explanation.

Comment: Absolutely never do this. eval is a major security risk.